# Stripping all instances of a string from a string in python

Tags: python

I have some results from a custom API that I need to parse and clean up. below is a sample output that is stored as a variable.

```
(DeviceConnectionInformation){
     DeviceName = "device1"
     ClientName = "ourclient"
     RegionName = "west"
     PrimaryIP = "1.1.1.1"
     OsVersionName = "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise"
     AccessMethod = None
     AccessIP = None
     Port = None
  },
  (DeviceConnectionInformation){
     DeviceName = "device2"
     ClientName = "ourclient"
     RegionName = None
     PrimaryIP = "1.1.1.2"
     OsVersionName = "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise"
     AccessMethod = None
     AccessIP = None
     Port = None
```

I need to strip any and all occurences of "(DeviceConnectionInformation){" and "}," that might occur, and leave the below format:

```
DeviceName = "device1"
ClientName = "ourclient"
RegionName = "west"
PrimaryIP = "1.1.1.1"
OsVersionName = "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise"
AccessMethod = None
AccessIP = None
Port = None

DeviceName = "device2"
ClientName = "ourclient"
RegionName = None
PrimaryIP = "1.1.1.2"
OsVersionName = "Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise"
AccessMethod = None
AccessIP = None
Port = None
```

Comment: Is it possible that these forbidden strings might appear in the data proper? Ex. `OsVersionName = "Kevin OS {Version 3.14},"`. Would you want to strip the ending curly bracket and comma there?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in string form, you can strip a literal string by replacing it with nothing:

```
val = val.replace("(DeviceConnectionInformation){", "")
val = val.replace("},", "")
```

However, I'd be cautious about this, especially the second case, because it pays no attention to the context.  For instance, if `},` occurs inside a quoted string your data, it will still be removed.

Comment: Cool, thats what I needed. Can't believe I hadn't seen replace yet, lol.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
for x in ("DevicConnectionInformation{\n", "},", "     "):
    data = data.replace(x, "")
```

of you get into trouble if, e.g., `},` appears in the values.